# check the month and day ignoring the year using php datetime object

Tags: php, datetime

I have 2 date range:

```
2014/01/28 - 2015/10/10 //first
2015/10/11 - 2014/01/27 //second
```

How to check using DateTime object in PHP only the month, day and ignoring the year if `2015/06/24` is between first or second date range. The expected answer that `2015/06/24` is between first date range, because 06/24 is between `01/28 - 10/10`

Thank you.

Comment: use [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to extract the day/month from both and do the appropriate `if()` comparisons...

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2014/01/28");
$date2 = new DateTime("2015/10/10");
$date_compare = new DateTime("2015/06/24");

if ($date_compare->format('m/d') > $date1->format('m/d') &&
$date_compare->format('m/d') <= $date2->format('m/d')) {
      echo $date_compare->format('m/d') . "fits";
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php < this will help you out with this

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think this method should take care of you.

```
function isWithinDayOfYearRange($rangeBegin, $rangeEnd, $dateToCheck)
{
    return $dateToCheck->format('md') > $rangeBegin->format('md') &&
        $dateToCheck->format('md') < $rangeEnd->format('md');
}
```